# Javascript crossfade

Tags: javascript

In all IE browsers I get the following error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'hasClassName': object is null or undefined

this relates to the following:

```
Crossfade.prototype = {
loaded : false,
initialize : function(elm, options) {
    var me = this, next, prev;
    this.elm = $(elm);
    this.counter = 0;
    this.prevSlide = null;
    var t_opt = {};
    for(t in Crossfade.Transition) {
        var trans = Crossfade.Transition[t];
        if(trans.className && this.elm.hasClassName(trans.className)) {
            t_opt = {transition:trans};
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hasClassName is not a native JavaScript construct. It's usually part of the prototype.js library.

Comment: `var t` please; otherwise you create a global variable which is especially bad for loop variables.

Comment: Oh OkI'm using the latest version of prototype so what should it be?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using [Prototype.j](http://prototypejs.org/)s:

```
   var trans = Crossfade.Transition[t];
    if(trans.className && this.elm.hasClassName(trans.className)) {
        t_opt = {transition:trans};
        break;
    }
```

`trans.className` is not scoped through Prototype. This needs to be: `$(trans).classNames()`

Comment: so this should be: var trans = Crossfade.Transition[t];
    if($(trans).classNames() && this.elm.hasClassName($(trans).classNames())) {
        t_opt = {transition:trans};
        break;
    }